# Disable automatic capitalisation of git checkout BRANCH_NAME in ZSH/oh-my-zsh

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using zsh 5.0.2 with oh-my-zsh plugin and whenever I do tab completion on `git checkout f` it comes out as:

`git checkout Feature\`

For some reason it's automatically searching uppercase branch names which isn't what I want. Is it possible to disable this behaviour but still retain the auto completion functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `~/.zshrc` set

```
CASE_SENSITIVE="true"
```

before `oh-my-zsh.sh` is sourced. If you use oh-my-zsh's default template for `~/.zshrc` this line is probably already there as a comment.